# Outliers in Categorical Data?

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, outliers

I am unable to find a solution to find outliers in categorical data. My data consists of combinations of rows. I want to mark outliers that differ in certain combinations.

In the above question as specified, I cannot cluster the data as a nonoutlier data row and the outlier row consisting of the same frequency.

My data looks something like this:

|  | **c1** | **c2** | **c3** | **c4** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **row1** | A | B | C | D |
| **row2** | A | B | C | D |
| **row3** | A | D | C | G |
| **row4** | NU | D | E | G |
| **row6** | NU | D | E | X |

Please suggest a valid logic to solve the issue.
I also tried to distribute the data based on frequency but I'm unable to assign a threshold as I'm unable to find a value to consider the data as outliers. Providing a way to find thresholds also can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no outlier detection methods for categorical data. The *notion* means nothing in this case. You might think like that:

> You have a sample of 10 with 9 females and 1 male. You might think the male is the outlier it's just the composition of your sample, not an outlier.

For an outlier to exist there must be a measure of distance between the items. Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/owl-analytics/categorical-outliers-dont-exist-8f4e82070cb2) for more information.

> Please suggest a valid logic to solve the issue. I Also tried to distribute the data based on frquency but i'm unable to assign a thresold as im unable to find a value to consider the data as outliers.Providing a way to find thresold also can help.

A solution could be to just `value_counts` your column so then you have the frequency of each element.

Comment: Thank You. Can you suggest how would word embeeding work for such a case. (I 'm very to new to word embeeding just eager to know will it work in such a case?)

Comment: No. I mean word embedding is about to provide a dense vector representation of the meaning of the word, but A, B, C don't mean such much all alone.

You can just  `df['c1'].value_counts()` for explanatory purpose but your questions are very unclair and I can't do any more with the information you give.

Comment: I'm sorry for not  being clear.Anyways i got a solution for my problem:).Your answers were really helpful.

Comment: BTW I was looking for a way to group the "rare" categories in a univariate categorical variable automatically. Like if I have A, B, C, D, E in which D and E have contributions of just 0.02, and 0.01 respectively, then it would be beneficial to group them as the "other" category. Now, handpicking a *threshold* like `<0.05` won't work for all cases. My question is if there is a way to automatically get the threshold or some kind of dynamic threshold from the given distribution to detect the "rare" categories. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tags you assigned, I guess you want to perform one-hot encoding in a later step. In this case you can use `sklearn`'s [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and specify the `min_frequency` parameter. If you specified the `min_frequency` parameter, rare categorical values will be assigned `'infrequend_sklearn'`.